# ¿Cómo mostrar varias consultas MySQL con INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, join, msql, inner

tengo un pequeño problema y espero que me puedan ayudar.

el caso es que yo tengo en mi base de datos dos tablas una llamada "Clientes" y la otra "Pedidos"

en la tabla clientes tengo estas columnas:
id, nombre, apellido, email,  teléfono

en la tabla pedidos tengo estas columnas:
id, cliente_id, producto, precio, direccion_envio

y quisiera que me muestre todos los resultados del cliente especificado ósea si en la tabla pedidos tengo varios datos con el mismo cliente_id que me lo muestre tango los datos de la tabla pedidos y la tabla clientes

ejemplo quiero que me muestre el nombre, apellido email, teléfono, producto, precio, dirección envió del cliente tal.

no se si me comprendieron lo que quise decir, espero su ayuda gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT nombre, apellido, email, telefono, producto, precio, direccion_envio 
FROM clientes
INNER JOIN pedidos ON clientes.id = pedidos.cliente_id
```

Comment: por favor leer [answer]